# Why CORBA run() depends on wall clock?

Tags: c++, linux, corba

`CORBAorb->run()` depends on wall clock. How can I change this behavior?

```
 CORBA::ORB_var orb = CORBA::ORB_init (argc, argv);
  const unsigned int orb_duration = 10000000; // 10 seconds    
    while(true)
    {
        ACE_Time_Value tv(0, orb_duration );
        tv.set(0, orb_duration );
        orb->run(tv);
      //orb->perform_work (tv);   
     //some task and back to orb;
    }
```

Here the `orb->run(tv)` is dependent on the system time, if I change my Linux system clock the orb run duration is varying! (It looks inside orb it depends on the wall clock time.)

I tried using `perform_work()` and it looks like it is not going to work out. Please suggest me a good way to overcome this wall clock reference of orb. I am new to Corba and don't have many ideas.

Comment: What makes you think it is varying? And by how much does it vary by?

Answer (score 0):

By default TAO does use the system time for the ORB run. For enabling the monotonic time support you have to add the following lines to the top of your ace/config.h file and recompile ACE/TAO and your application.

```
#define TAO_USE_HR_TIME_POLICY_STRATEGY
#define ACE_HAS_CLOCK_GETTIME_MONOTONIC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use orb run duration.
You can start a new thread in which you call orb->run() and when you want to stop it just call orb->shutdown() from main thread.